# knitr fails on Stan chunk with cache=TRUE

Tags: r, knitr, rstan

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1064) (marked as fixed for knitr v1.12), it should be possible to cache Stan chunks in knitr so that the Stan model object doesn't need to be re-compiled every time we knit the file.

However, using knitr v1.20 (R v3.5.1 within RStudio v1.1.463), when knitting the file for the second time (so that the cache has already been built), I get an error:

```
Quitting from lines 9-18 (Testing_Stan_cache.Rmd) 
Error in fun(environment()) : invalid first argument
Calls: <Anonymous> ... call_block -> <Anonymous> -> lazyLoad -> lazyLoadDBexec -> fun
Execution halted
```

Example Rmarkdown file (lines 9-18 mentioned in the error are the Stan chunk):

````
---
title: "Testing Stan cache"
output: html_document
---

## Stan model

```{stan output.var="ex1", cache=TRUE}
data {
  int<lower=0, upper=1> X[100];
}
parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> p;
}
model {
  X ~ bernoulli(p);
}
```

## Run the model 

```{r}
library(rstan)
fit <- sampling(ex1, data=list(X = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3)))
print(fit)
```
````

I've also tried it with `cache.lazy=FALSE` in the Stan chunk options, but get a different error:

```
Quitting from lines 23-26 (Testing_Stan_cache.Rmd) 
Error in sampling(ex1, data = list(X = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3))) : 
  object 'ex1' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> sampling
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of **knitr**, which [I just fixed on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/5188c38e8562e9b07d4b5664539490ab78069f8d). Please try the current development version:

```
remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```